# Can I install both Ubuntu-Server and Desktop on my computer

Tags: dual-boot, server

Can I install both of them on my machine 
or is there any problem with that?

And if it is possible can you tell me how, please?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Yes, but why?  The default way would be creating a dual-boot system, with one being Desktop, the other being the Server and only one at a time running.  Why would you want this.  I'd suggest just installing one, and add whatever you want to have (eg. desktop & add file|web|mail serving functions to it).   You install one (partitioning disk to use only a %) then install the other (using the unused portion of the disk).  The second will setup GRUB (assuming legacy) to have it ask you which you want to boot (you may want to modify names to be clearer)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu Server and Desktop are two different installers for the same operating system.  The difference is in the packages they install by default: Ubuntu Desktop installs a desktop environment by default, and Ubuntu Server doesn't.

Once you have installed Ubuntu the distinction between Desktop and Server does not remain, just the selection of packages that have been installed.  You can install the same packages regardless of which installer you used initially.

If you want to be able to use your Ubuntu installation as a server but have a desktop environment as well, you can just use the Ubuntu Desktop installer.  Or, having installed Ubuntu without a desktop environment you can add one by installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package.